# How Can I save post requests to mongoengine using django forms?

Tags: django, django-forms, mongoengine

If I have a mongoengine document,

```
class Blog(Document):
    text = StringField()
    tags = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField(Tag))

class Tag(EmbeddedDocument):
    tag = StringField()
```

How can I write a django form to validate and save the post data

```
{
    "text": "My first blog post",
    "tags": [
        {"tag":"mongo"}, {"tag":"django"}
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use `mongoengine>=0.8` then:

```
blog = Blog.from_json('''{
    "text": "My first blog post",
    "tags": [
        {"tag":"mongo"}, {"tag":"django"}
    ]
}''').save()
```

or if you already have dict:

```
blog = Blog._from_son({
    "text": "My first blog post",
    "tags": [
        {"tag":"mongo"}, {"tag":"django"}
    ]
}).save()
```

Comment: How does this all fit in with django forms?